# Equal Derivatives of differente Functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)$ is a function whose derivate $f'(x) = b$.

Which two functions ($g(x)$ and $h(x)$) can fullfill the following conditions:

1) $g(x) \leq h(x)$

2) $g(0) = 0 = h(0)$

3) $g'(x) = b = h'(x)$

4) $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$

Comment: Start with the fact that $f(x)=bx+C$, where $C$ is some constant.

Comment: If C is some constant, the it wouldn´t pass through 0. It´s necessary that both g(x) and h(x) are = ONLY in 0.

Comment: @Jeje, what if $C$ is the constant $0$?

Comment: Ok, but which function g(x) and h(x) would have that same derivative, but are only equal at 0 ? @BenMillwood

Comment: @Jeje: Edit condition 3 if needed.

Comment: Assume condictions can´t be edited @SalechAlhasov

Comment: Is it $ g'(x) = b = h(x) $ or  $g'(x) = b = h'(x) $?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.... It´s g'(x) = b = h'(x) @SalechAlhasov

Comment: Ok, then, from condition 3: $f(x)=bx+C_1$ and $g(x)=bx+C_2$ and $h(x)=bx+C_3$. and from condition 2: $C_2=C_3$

Comment: But remermber that g(x) must be < or = to h(x) and if C2=C3 then they would b the same, wouldn´t they? @SalechAlhasov

Comment: Read again that sentence of yours, especially the part: "g(x) must be < or = to h(x)"

Comment: You´re right, thanks @SalechAlhasov

Comment: But, if the question goes: g(x) < than h(x) ... How would it be? @SalechAlhasov

Comment: Then: $C_2<C_3$.

Comment: But being C2 < C3 implies that one of the wouldn´t be 0 and condition 2 wouldn´t be accomplished